# Google heatmap plotting with wrong gradient based on weight

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap, latitude-longitude

I was having some problem with Google Heatmap. The result that I am getting as such:

[image]

The following as the code for me to populate the array for heatmap, I declared the heatmapData as global array so that I can be used in some other function:

```
var heatmapData = [];
function addForecastMarker(marker){
    // code to plot marker here

    heatmapData.push({location: new google.maps.LatLng(marker['lat'], marker['lng']), weight: marker['total'].toFixed(2)}); 
}
```

When I tried to print out the above data to ensure I am retriving the correct data, I am getting these which mean my population for heatmapData is no problem:

```
['lat: 1.3920108, lng: 103.8951026, weight: 37.80',
'lat: 1.3164324, lng: 103.8943035, weight: 282.40',
'lat: 1.4055193, lng: 103.9119956, weight: 104.40',
'lat: 1.3669051, lng: 103.9645099, weight: 112.70',
'lat: 1.299765, lng: 103.7883239, weight: 68.60',
'lat: 1.3808263, lng: 103.8793951, weight: 305.35',
'lat: 1.301906, lng: 103.9049735, weight: 240.50',
'lat: 1.3890362, lng: 103.8289738, weight: 77.70',
'lat: 1.346858, lng: 103.9379999, weight: 147.40',
'lat: 1.3022747, lng: 103.8764825, weight: 14.75',
'lat: 1.3735984, lng: 103.8863068, weight: 241.20',
'lat: 1.2869242, lng: 103.8188638, weight: 13.20',
'lat: 40.3096226, lng: -73.9785844, weight: 189.40',
'lat: 1.3728821, lng: 103.8476553, weight: 102.50',
'lat: 1.4356078, lng: 103.8368437, weight: 59.05',
'lat: 40.2232011, lng: -76.0360669, weight: 42.65',
'lat: 1.2823, lng: 103.8253157, weight: 38.60',
'lat: 1.302012, lng: 103.836271, weight: 93.80',
'lat: 1.3393411, lng: 103.7053874, weight: 3.60',
'lat: 1.287303, lng: 103.805329, weight: 66.40',
'lat: 1.2927292, lng: 103.859401, weight: 45.60',
'lat: 1.2875947, lng: 103.8340063, weight: 127.90',
'lat: 1.3584368, lng: 103.7495064, weight: 90.50']
```

Lat followed by Lng followed by weight.

After populated the global array, when I tried to plot out the heatmap in another function (At this point when I print out the heatmapData, the array is already populated so I am pretty sure it is not due to that problem):

```js
var fheatmap;
var fheatmapLayer = [];
var fgradient = ['rgba(185, 185, 203, 0)', 'rgba(145, 145, 192, 0)',
  'rgba(65, 65, 207, 0)', 'rgba(30, 30, 229, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 185, 255, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 215, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 255, 15, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
  'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)', 'rgba(255, 235, 0, 1)',
  'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
];

function drawForecastHeatmap() {
  console.log(heatmapData);
  var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatmapData);

  fheatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray,
    gradient: fgradient,
    map: forecastmap,
    radius: 10,
    dissipating: true,
  });
  // push layer of heat map into array to ease the clearing of layers
  fheatmapLayer.push(fheatmap);
  fheatmap.setMap(forecastmap);
}

var forecastmap;

function initMap() {
  forecastmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('forecastmap'), {
    center: {
      lat: 1.352083,
      lng: 103.81983600000001
    },
    zoom: 11
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box-header">
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      <h4 class="box-title">Forecasted Hot Spots by Subtype in 2018</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      <div id="forecastmap" style="width:100%;height:300px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not have any other CSS to style the map other than the 'heat' gradient I defined myself.

The code above supposed to produce something like this:

[image]

Any ideas why the heatmap layer is behaving like this?

Comment: Anyone?? I have no idea why it behaves like this

Comment: Why voted close? I think I have posted enough details regarding the problem. If not, please let me know and I will update the question

Comment: You have asked a good question but even if I try to figure out what might be going wrong I can't because Google Maps API is a very big library and there can be many things that can be contributing to the issue. What you can do to make it possible for others to help is to isolate the problem and create a JsFiddle demo so that others can test it out and help you.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Hey thanks so much! But the strange thing is, I am using the same code with slight modifications on variable names from the same project for the heatmap. The original one was working fine but not this :( Just wondering why the 'heat' will resulting in square, I thought it is supposed to be like the second picture. Is it some map initialization problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (can't use a picture of data).

Comment: As @geocodezip said, providing a live example that demonstrates the problem is far better in this regard as I said earlier, not only one but there can be several things that's contributing to the issue, and also you said the same code worked in another project of yours. 

Create a demo here: jsfiddle.net will be easier for both you and others who want to help :)

Comment: @geocodezip Updated question! Because my code contains very depth level of nested Promise to get the data out so I guess it would be hard to extract certain part and put in jsfiddle. But by just looking at these, could you figure out what might possibly went wrong? I managed to plot out marker at each 'heat' location though

Comment: @DeepakKamat The only weird thing is when I do this to cast it to Number instead of String: weight: parseFloat(marker['total'].toFixed(2)) , the heatmap layer simply broken. If I take out the weight attribute, it will be broken as well. But this thing is not happening to my first heat map under the same project.

Comment: Oh. 

See, if it is not possible to extract the data in the demo like you are doing in your actual project then instead of getting the data from the source use the data that you get inside of the demo i.e hard-code the data array in the code and just refer to the variable that contains it.

Comment: There are undefined variables in the posted code `fheatmapLayer`. If I address those and get a heatmap to display, I can't reproduce the issue with the provided code/data (from looking at the picture, I would guess it is a CSS issue, but you haven't provided any HTML/CSS.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (preferably a SO code snippet, but a jsfiddle would work).

Comment: @geocodezip Hey I have updated all the codes related to the heatmap.